# Help to ID a 16 pin IC, damaged by carelessness

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I need help with the ID of a 16pin IC. 
In an act of 100% carelessness, two cables were incorrectly inserted into one of the controls, which resulted in a 16pin IC getting hot and virtually destroying the ID printed on the IC.

Along the bottom I believe I can make out XNAH0828, and the latter part of the top line is perhaps one of these
 ????  8084CPE         ?????  3084CPE       or even  3Q84CPE  but I think the latter unlikely…

Via Google I haven't been able to identify the specific IC. The circuit board was made or designed by I.T.Solutions 2010.

It links to a small LCD display and sends signals to the stitch regulator system.

I also Googled I.T Solutions, there is a company with that name but not sure it is the correct one.

The IC is in a base and although damaged, I have sufficient skill to de-solder and replace the base.

I know I am asking a lot, but at the moment we are waiting to see if Tin Lizzie (Utah based) who make the machine can find a replacement board.

[image: photo of damaged IC]

Comment: What does "in a base" mean? If the IC is in a socket, there should be no need to desolder anything.

Comment: It looks very dusty - could you give it a once over with a small brush an re-photograph - might get a bit more of the chip id.

Comment: That's a [Freescale Semiconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freescale_Semiconductor) logo (now NXP) on the left, which should help narrow down the search a bit.

Comment: Also look at other chips on the board - there may be more than one of this type

Comment: @DaveTweed, just read the question, he spells it out. If the base is the IC socket, he says he has "sufficient skill to de-solder and replace the base". The IC socket is damaged, ass well as the IC.

Comment: @TonyM: Are you sure that "base" = "socket"? That's what I'm trying to clarify.

Comment: For a moment, I thought of TL084 but that's 14-pin. Are you able to clean it gently with water to reveal more or have your tried that already?

Comment: @DaveTweed, oh - that's not what "What does "in a base" mean? If the IC is in a socket, there should be no need to desolder anything" says, is it? Silly me, so you really meant "By base, do you mean IC socket?".

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just the most obvious fault on the board. Even if you can miraculously find a replacement programmed chip (if it is in fact programmed)  probability of that fixing the board is slim at best.

Answer (score 23):

Looks like a Freescale MC908QB4CPE microcontroller. There are sources for the chip or near-equivalent replacements, but unless you have the code to be burned to it and a programmer to burn it with there is no way to create a duplicate of the original by yourself.

Comment: Yeah, and if it killed the processor there's an excellent chance that the voltage regulator(s) and other parts are damaged as well.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help.    The fact it is the only "plug in"  IC on the board I wondered if it was a programmable item.  There is a small LCD screen attached to the board that gives text readings for settings on the machine.     I know there is a risk of other items being damaged.    Thanks again to everyone.  It seems we may now be in the hands of the manufacturers, who do not have the best record for service.  Regards   Peter